# Dapper SqlException and Unobserved exception

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, dapper

I have an issue with the following code when the T-SQL proc raises an error (SQLException)

```
    var result = await conn.QueryMultipleAsync("Inventory.uspLoadItems", new
    {
        dbId = obj.myId,
    },
    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    var items = await result.ReadAsync();
    var specificItems = MyCustomMapper.MapTo<MyItem>((dynamic)items);
```

I'm using Dapper version 1.50.2.

The process is thrown into an Unobserved Exception.

I can follow the exception all the way up to the WebApi controller method. <del>But when the controller method exists, another (spawn and unfinished) thread continue to execute at `var items = await items.ReadAsync();` even if the WebApi session has been terminated (GC collected?).</del> (*Text deleted due to me misunderstanding information in Parallell Stack window. The exception failed at ReadAsync, not QueryMultipleAsync and hence **didn't** continue after the exception*). 
Looks like a threading issue in Dapper, but I'm not sure.

**UPDATE**

I found the follwing link at Microsoft Connect that seems to be highly related to this topic.
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2592987/sqldatareader-nextresultasync-causes-unobserved-task-exception-even-when-awaited

So, for anyone else who experiences this behavior. You'll have to wait for the next .NET update.

Not a Dapper problem, but if Dapper-contributers could find a temporary work-around, that would be nice :)

For now I change all my ReadAsync to Read (synchronous) to avoid this SqlDataReader bug.

Comment: don't think it's a threading issue.
await result.ReadAsync() will be called in separate thread since you have another await before that. can u post the exception here

Comment: In `Async-Await`, there's no thread except calling thread, Check:
http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

Comment: Could you try the Sync version of `QueryMultiple`, and check if a similar exception is observed. In this case how do you know Web API session is Garbage Collected (there's no way to know), just the context is lost. In background IO process is on an since there's no handler available, it may give an unobserved exception. Do you await at the top of call stack, in the Web API controller, which is important in this case, to receive the result of the call.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj  I've tried to reproduce in a console application with no luck. Maybe Dapper is innocent after all. Now I suspect that this issue has something to do with how Katana (OWIN selfhost), WebApi2 and/or the use of CancellationToken injections in controller methods. The problem seems to manifest itself when a stored procedure raises an error (SQLException). I need to investigate further

Comment: @MrinalKamboj: I'm using await at every step down the silo, from the controller -> service -> repository. I await the exception and it bubbles back to the await'ed call in the controller. When I step out of the exception handler in the controller method and out of the method itself, I observed a thread (using the parallel stack window) trying to continue in the repository method. This thread seemed to cause the unobserved exception. When I used the "Single" variant of the Dapper methods, this didn't happen.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj I found a link to a bug in SqlDataReader. See question update

Comment: It would be interesting to see all the code in the "await chain". You claim that it's all correctly awaited but I maintain that it's not. There are many subtle issues possible...

Comment: @usr I totally agree with you, and I've checked and re-checked the way calls are awaited down the call chain. The continuation was a misunderstanding from my side. See my comment to your answer below

Answer (score 3):

> another (spawn and unfinished) thread continue to execute at var items = await items.ReadAsync();

Sounds like the function that all this code exists in executes asynchronously and is not awaited or otherwise synchronized with. The main request finishes while this function is still running (this is not a guess, it's proven by your observation that the code executes after the controller is done). Then, if this code crashes the exception is unobserved.

It would be an incorrect fix to ignore unobserved exceptions. I recommend doing that anyway, but the correct fix is to await the task that this code is part of.

Since it is *your* code that is still running it's not a framework bug. The bug you linked to might cause framework code to execute later and unobservedly, but it will not cause statements after your await to run (again).

Comment: I agree with you. I see now that my observation might be wrong. I was using the Parallell Stacks window when code was halted in my TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException handler. In the thread leading to the exception, a green line (executing line) was shown at ReadAsync after the controller method finished. I thought QueryMultipleAsync should raise the SqlException and therefore assumed, incorrectly, that code was continuing after the exception. Seems that exceptions are not raised until ReadAsync and that the Parallell Stack window showed that exception's origin correctly.